# Conversion from sql to elastic search query

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch, aggregation

How can i convert the following sql query into elastic search query?

```
SELECT sum(`price_per_unit`*`quantity`) as orders 
FROM       `order_demormalize` 
WHERE date(`order_date`)='2014-04-15'
```

Comment: Cleaned up formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use scripts to compute the product of values. For newer versions of Elasticsearch, enable dynamic scripting by adding the line `script.disable_dynamic: false` in `elasticsearch.yml` file. Note that this may leave a security hole in your Elasticsearch cluster. So enable scripting judiciously. Try the query below:

```
POST <indexname>/<typename>/_search?search_type=count
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "order_date": "2014-04-15"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "orders": {
         "sum": {
            "script": "doc['price_per_unit'].value * doc['quantity'].value"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to access **script** ie doc['price_per_unit'].value .

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: I am using elasticsearch - 1.4.4

Comment: Then you need to enable scripting by adding the line `script.disable_dynamic: false` in `elasticsearch.yml` file